# Getting a VISA STAMP in the UK Border Control

Tags: visas, uk, airports, passport-stamps

I am from Chile and I am going to study for a semester (6 months) in the UK. The University in which I was accepeted informed me that I do not need to apply for a Visa as a chilean citizen going to the UK, so, because of that I am going to get a visa stamp at the UK border control in te airport if I take with me some documents.

Does it imply any problem in getting just the visa stamp?
Is it legal ?
Can I visit other countries around Europe if I just get the visa stamp?

Please. I am travelling in just one month more... and I do not understand well the procedures

Comment: As to visiting other European countries, as a citizen of Chile, you can visit the Schengen area (most of the rest of the EU) without a visa, for no more than 90 days in any 180-day period.  I am not sure about Ireland, which is not in Schengen.

Comment: may be unrelated but just to understand better are you going to Cranfield?

Answer (score 5):

For a program of study of six months or less, [Chilean nationals do not need a visa](https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa/y/chile/study/six_months_or_less) to visit the UK, but you do need to bring your [documents](https://www.gov.uk/study-visit-visa/documents-you-must-provide) to show at the border.

In particular, you need to:

- Prove you are enrolled in a course of study not exceeding six months
- Prove you can support yourself financially, or that a sponsor will support you
- Show where you will stay in the UK
- Provide [certified translations](https://www.gov.uk/certifying-a-document) of non-English documents